# How to sort all data of a single column on realm database in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm, swift5

How the database looks like:

[image: From realm browser]

Here is my data model:

class TodoData: Object {

```
@objc dynamic var todos: String = String()
@objc dynamic var times: String = String()
@objc dynamic var rows: Bool = Bool()
@objc dynamic var primaryID: Int = Int()
```

}

I am adding single row data every time but I need to only sort the primary ID column in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your realm config to a variable.  The code below assumes you are using the default local config.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

Set an optional property in your VC to be of type [Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections)?.  *Don't forget to import RealmSwift at the top of the VC.

```
var todos: Results<TodoData>?
```

Assign in ViewDidLoad

```
todos = realm.objects(TodoData.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "primaryID", ascending: true)
```

Bonus tip:  Realm Results also support NSPredicates for filtering.  [Realm sorting](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections)

Comment: Hi. I want to make any row from 'false' to 'true' or vice versa depending on table view did select and did deselect method.

That mean's I need to update the existing value. How to do that. My code is not working it's creating another row instead of updating the existing one.

Thanks.

Comment: In the didSelectRow at method, add:  

`let tappedTodo = todos?[indexPath.row]
try! realm.write {  
   tappedTodo?.toggle()  
}`

Comment: It's working! Thanks, man!

but it would be tappedTodo?.rows.toggle()